# OpenCL loop effect on GPU performance

Tags: performance, for-loop, opencl, gpu

I'm developing a set of OpenCL kernels, where each of them are executing the same amount of floating point operations. Each kernel has a "for" loop and inside each loop there are unrolled operations. The only difference between kernels is, each kernel is looping a different number than the others. In other words some kernel have more unrolled operations and less iterations, and some other have more iterations with less unrolled operations.

Here are the kernels I've written:

Add16-20Unroll-282Iters (Iterating 282 times and each iteration does 20 calculation)

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
__kernel void Add16(__global double *data, int nIters) {
  int gid = get_global_id(0), globalSize = get_global_size(0);
  double s = data[gid];
  double16 s0 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  for (int j = 0; j < nIters; ++j){
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
  }
   data[gid] = s0.s0+s0.s1+s0.s2+s0.s3+s0.s4+s0.s5+s0.s6+s0.s7+s0.s8+s0.s9+s0.sa+s0.sb+s0.sc+s0.sd+s0.se+s0.sf;
}
```

Add16-30Unroll-141Iters (Iterating 141 times and each iteration does 30 calculation)

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
__kernel void Add16(__global double *data, int nIters) {
  int gid = get_global_id(0), globalSize = get_global_size(0);
  double s = data[gid];
  double16 s0 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  for (int j = 0; j < nIters; ++j){
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s0=10.f-s0;
  }
   data[gid] = s0.s0+s0.s1+s0.s2+s0.s3+s0.s4+s0.s5+s0.s6+s0.s7+s0.s8+s0.s9+s0.sa+s0.sb+s0.sc+s0.sd+s0.se+s0.sf;
}
```

The same for two other kernels, "Add16-60Unroll-70Iters", "Add16-120Unroll-35Iters", and "Add16-240Unroll-17Iters".

My first expectation is, kernels with much more iterations perform worse than unrolled versions, but unfortunately it's not the case. Here are the performance results I'm calculating in my code.

```
test                            atts            units   median  mean    stddev          min     max     trial0  trial1  trial2  trial3  trial4  trial5  trial6  trial7  trial8  trial9
Add16-20Unroll-282Iters-DP      Size:2097152    GFLOPS  704.111 704.16  0.158984        704.009 704.501 704.019 704.064 704.37  704.024 704.234 704.501 704.009 704.188 704.158 704.033
Add16-30Unroll-141Iters-DP      Size:2097152    GFLOPS  704.622 704.698 0.422365        704.243 705.527 704.318 704.671 704.256 704.574 704.243 704.681 704.87  704.47  705.527 705.37
Add16-60Unroll-70Iters-DP       Size:2097152    GFLOPS  705.891 705.844 0.201042        705.286 706.058 705.864 705.974 705.937 705.871 705.919 706.058 705.747 705.87  705.286 705.91
Add16-120Unroll-35Iters-DP      Size:2097152    GFLOPS  705.912 705.851 0.292976        705.284 706.373 705.91  705.67  705.962 705.987 706.373 705.815 706.103 705.284 705.914 705.493
Add16-240Unroll-17Iters-DP      Size:2097152    GFLOPS  676.128 676.217 0.373075        675.777 676.845 676.105 676.266 676.151 675.777 675.968 676.839 675.787 676.49  676.845 675.94
```

So my question is, do I miss something here? Or is it possible that specific optimizations are happening while kernels being compiled?

In general, how do you suggest to observe the implication of loops on OpenCL performance while running over GPUs?

EDIT:

Here I've changed the kernels in order to make sure there is no dependency with the operations inside for loop. So instead of doing computation only on s0, I'm create s(ids). Here is the modified kernel for Add16-Unroll20-282Iters:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
__kernel void Add16(__global double *data, int nIters) {
  int gid = get_global_id(0), globalSize = get_global_size(0);
  double s = data[gid];
  double16 s0 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s1 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s2 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s3 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s4 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s5 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s6 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s7 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s8 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s9 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s10 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s11 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s12 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s13 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s14 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s15 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s16 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s17 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s18 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  double16 s19 = s + (double16)(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5);
  for (int j = 0; j < nIters; ++j){
 s0=10.f-s0;
 s1=10.f-s1;
 s2=10.f-s2;
 s3=10.f-s3;
 s4=10.f-s4;
 s5=10.f-s5;
 s6=10.f-s6;
 s7=10.f-s7;
 s8=10.f-s8;
 s9=10.f-s9;
 s10=10.f-s10;
 s11=10.f-s11;
 s12=10.f-s12;
 s13=10.f-s13;
 s14=10.f-s14;
 s15=10.f-s15;
 s16=10.f-s16;
 s17=10.f-s17;
 s18=10.f-s18;
 s19=10.f-s19;
  }
   data[gid] += s0.s0+s0.s1+s0.s2+s0.s3+s0.s4+s0.s5+s0.s6+s0.s7+s0.s8+s0.s9+s0.sa+s0.sb+s0.sc+s0.sd+s0.se+s0.sf;
   data[gid] += s1.s0+s1.s1+s1.s2+s1.s3+s1.s4+s1.s5+s1.s6+s1.s7+s1.s8+s1.s9+s1.sa+s1.sb+s1.sc+s1.sd+s1.se+s1.sf;
   data[gid] += s2.s0+s2.s1+s2.s2+s2.s3+s2.s4+s2.s5+s2.s6+s2.s7+s2.s8+s2.s9+s2.sa+s2.sb+s2.sc+s2.sd+s2.se+s2.sf;
   data[gid] += s3.s0+s3.s1+s3.s2+s3.s3+s3.s4+s3.s5+s3.s6+s3.s7+s3.s8+s3.s9+s3.sa+s3.sb+s3.sc+s3.sd+s3.se+s3.sf;
   data[gid] += s4.s0+s4.s1+s4.s2+s4.s3+s4.s4+s4.s5+s4.s6+s4.s7+s4.s8+s4.s9+s4.sa+s4.sb+s4.sc+s4.sd+s4.se+s4.sf;
   data[gid] += s5.s0+s5.s1+s5.s2+s5.s3+s5.s4+s5.s5+s5.s6+s5.s7+s5.s8+s5.s9+s5.sa+s5.sb+s5.sc+s5.sd+s5.se+s5.sf;
   data[gid] += s6.s0+s6.s1+s6.s2+s6.s3+s6.s4+s6.s5+s6.s6+s6.s7+s6.s8+s6.s9+s6.sa+s6.sb+s6.sc+s6.sd+s6.se+s6.sf;
   data[gid] += s7.s0+s7.s1+s7.s2+s7.s3+s7.s4+s7.s5+s7.s6+s7.s7+s7.s8+s7.s9+s7.sa+s7.sb+s7.sc+s7.sd+s7.se+s7.sf;
   data[gid] += s8.s0+s8.s1+s8.s2+s8.s3+s8.s4+s8.s5+s8.s6+s8.s7+s8.s8+s8.s9+s8.sa+s8.sb+s8.sc+s8.sd+s8.se+s8.sf;
   data[gid] += s9.s0+s9.s1+s9.s2+s9.s3+s9.s4+s9.s5+s9.s6+s9.s7+s9.s8+s9.s9+s9.sa+s9.sb+s9.sc+s9.sd+s9.se+s9.sf;
   data[gid] += s10.s0+s10.s1+s10.s2+s10.s3+s10.s4+s10.s5+s10.s6+s10.s7+s10.s8+s10.s9+s10.sa+s10.sb+s10.sc+s10.sd+s10.se+s10.sf;
   data[gid] += s11.s0+s11.s1+s11.s2+s11.s3+s11.s4+s11.s5+s11.s6+s11.s7+s11.s8+s11.s9+s11.sa+s11.sb+s11.sc+s11.sd+s11.se+s11.sf;
   data[gid] += s12.s0+s12.s1+s12.s2+s12.s3+s12.s4+s12.s5+s12.s6+s12.s7+s12.s8+s12.s9+s12.sa+s12.sb+s12.sc+s12.sd+s12.se+s12.sf;
   data[gid] += s13.s0+s13.s1+s13.s2+s13.s3+s13.s4+s13.s5+s13.s6+s13.s7+s13.s8+s13.s9+s13.sa+s13.sb+s13.sc+s13.sd+s13.se+s13.sf;
   data[gid] += s14.s0+s14.s1+s14.s2+s14.s3+s14.s4+s14.s5+s14.s6+s14.s7+s14.s8+s14.s9+s14.sa+s14.sb+s14.sc+s14.sd+s14.se+s14.sf;
   data[gid] += s15.s0+s15.s1+s15.s2+s15.s3+s15.s4+s15.s5+s15.s6+s15.s7+s15.s8+s15.s9+s15.sa+s15.sb+s15.sc+s15.sd+s15.se+s15.sf;
   data[gid] += s16.s0+s16.s1+s16.s2+s16.s3+s16.s4+s16.s5+s16.s6+s16.s7+s16.s8+s16.s9+s16.sa+s16.sb+s16.sc+s16.sd+s16.se+s16.sf;
   data[gid] += s17.s0+s17.s1+s17.s2+s17.s3+s17.s4+s17.s5+s17.s6+s17.s7+s17.s8+s17.s9+s17.sa+s17.sb+s17.sc+s17.sd+s17.se+s17.sf;
   data[gid] += s18.s0+s18.s1+s18.s2+s18.s3+s18.s4+s18.s5+s18.s6+s18.s7+s18.s8+s18.s9+s18.sa+s18.sb+s18.sc+s18.sd+s18.se+s18.sf;
   data[gid] += s19.s0+s19.s1+s19.s2+s19.s3+s19.s4+s19.s5+s19.s6+s19.s7+s19.s8+s19.s9+s19.sa+s19.sb+s19.sc+s19.sd+s19.se+s19.sf;
}
```

Comment: unrolling helps when there are independent operations. All kernels here have same dependency at each line. Each line waiting the other line result to continue so it doesnt matter to unroll or not. Try again with more variables than just s0. Or maybe GFLOPS value is already at max.

Comment: Good point. So seems like the compiler counts them as dependency and will not optimize it. I think I should create more variables to make sure there are no more dependencies out there.

Comment: Even an igpu(Intel hd400) gets more performance like that.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I have made changes into my kernels based on your suggestion (The kernel is added into my questions as above). Right now the performance is terrible. Something around 7 GFlops. Isn't every line of my code supposed to run in parallel?

Comment: `data[gid] +=` is used many times instead of once. You can add all at once in same line to access global memory only once. Also kernel is using 256 registers now. Too much. Use just 4 vectors instead of 16. Then 64 variables maybe fit in compute unit. Also decrease local workgroup size to let them have more private memory per thread. Maybe you should start with only 2 accumulators, if faster then go for 4, if even faster, then try 8, if slower, fallback to 4

Comment: I have specific questions regarding your comments: 1) How specifically I have 256 registers? Could you please elaborate how did you count it? 2) When you say use 4 vectors, does it mean using double4 instead of double16?

Comment: 16xdouble16 = 256 primitive registers(vgpr). I suggested only 4xdouble16.

Comment: Here's what I've found so far. For one of my double precision experiments, I was able to achieve around 1400 GFLOPS. I've checked the Tesla K40 datasheet and seems like that's also the theoretical peak performance. Now my question is, if every line inside my for loop has data dependency how it could reach the peak performance. I'm really confused why dependency between consecutive operations does not affect the performance, as it's being said everywhere?

Comment: Let me give you also a background about my intention for demonstrate loop effect. I want to show FPGA will outperform GPUs while there is a data dependency in the application, and I tried to use For loop to implement that.

Comment: could the opencl compiler be optimizing it to a non-dependency version already? tesla's drivers could be good.